# Commandline/hotkey way to duplicate displays on both monitor

Tags: windows-7, multiple-monitors, display-settings

I have 2 external monitors connected to a win7 desktop. My displays are setup as "Extend displays to both monitors".

Only one of the monitors is connected to a UPS.

When the power goes, I want to use a commandline/hotkey to duplicate the display on both monitors.

Appreciate your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [<kbd>Windows</kbd> + <kbd>P</kbd>:](http://www.addictivetips.com/windows-tips/30-windows-7-hotkeys-ultimate-guide/)

> It is used to adjust the presentation options of the display on your
>   computer or projector.

[image]